# Is is possible to use import() in type generic dynamically

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to use import in types to import declarations dynamically?

```
type Import<T extends string> = Promise<typeof import(T)>

declare function CustomImport<T extends string>(name: string): Promise<typeof import(T)>
```